# Add Dotted border style using multiple SVG PATH elements

Tags: html, svg

I am trying to add dotted border style with different `stroke-width` such as 1px, 2px, 3px, 4px and 5px for the below SVG using `<path>` element instead of `<style>` attribute. But, the actual SVG output using `<path>` does not match the expected output when using the `<style>` attribute.

You can replace the style attribute within the SVG below with different border size such 1px, 2px, and so on to check the expected output for different border sizes.

Expected Output (SVG using  attribute):

```html
<svg height="100" width="200" 
     style="border:5px dotted #000000!important;background-color:#ccffff;">
</svg>
```

Actual Output (SVG using  element):

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="100" width="200">
  <g>
    <path d="M02.5,0 V97.5" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" stroke-dashoffset="5" stroke-dasharray="0 10" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round"/>
    <path d="M197.5,0 V97.5" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" stroke-dashoffset="5" stroke-dasharray="0 10" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round"/>
    <path d="M0,2.5 H197.5" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" stroke-dashoffset="5" stroke-dasharray="0 10" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round"/>
    <path d="M0,97.5 H197.5" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" stroke-dashoffset="5" stroke-dasharray="0 10" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

The above snippet is using multiple SVG Path elements instead of using single SVG Path element solution as mentioned in this post [SVG Dotted border style using  element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75939472/svg-dotted-border-style-using-path-element/75966372#75966372) and this solution is not a generic one since it does not cater different border sizes dynamically.

I am looking for a more generic solution where if I change the border size to say 1 or 2 or even 3, then the values within the `"d"` attribute should change accordingly along with other attributes such as `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dahsoffset` and most importantly the actual output should match the expected output.

Comment: A ``stroke-dash-array="0 10"`` can never  "fill" a 197,5 length line. What defines your box? The SVG size?

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman, I have corrected the code snippet for the Actual Output scenario. Thanks for pointing out the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between CSS dotted `border-style` and SVG `stroke-dasharray` is that SVG will never adjust the gap lengths to fill the path length. To solve this, you will need a number of extra assumptions (should the adaption work for the total path length? between every vertex?) and some runtime computation in JS. In short: it would be best to write a web component for your specific use case.

If you want a dot exactly at the beginning and the end of the complete path, you can fake it by not describing the distance between the dots, but by counting the total number of dots to show. Just add the attribute `pathLength` and give it a value equal to the number of dots (plus a very small fraction), and prescribe a gap length of 1 in the dasharray. You need to add that small fraction because otherwise the last dot will be missing.

```css
.dotted {
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-dasharray: 0, 1;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 30">
  <path d="M10,0V30M90,0V30" style="stroke:blue;stroke-width:0.2" />
  <g style="fill:none;stroke:black">
    <path d="M10,5 H 90" class="dotted" style="stroke-width:1px" pathLength="40.001" />
    <path d="M10,15 H 90" class="dotted" style="stroke-width:2px" pathLength="18.001" />
    <path d="M10,25 H 90" class="dotted" style="stroke-width:2px" pathLength="15.001" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

If it is more important to adjust the dot/dash distance according to stroke width, that can be done relatively easy with CSS variables. Note that this will not work if you write the `stroke-...` properties as presentation attributes. They must be used as style properties, same as the definition of the variable value.

Normally, you could leave off the `px` units for SVG length values. But if you write them in conjunction with the `calc()` functional notation, I found they may be needed for the correct interpretation.

```css
.dotted {
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-width: var(--size);
  stroke-dasharray: 0, calc(2 * var(--size));
  stroke-dashoffset: var(--size)
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 30">
  <path d="M10,0V30M90,0V30" style="stroke:blue;stroke-width:0.2" />
  <g style="fill:none;stroke:black">
    <path d="M10,5 H 90" class="dotted" style="--size:1px" />
    <path d="M10,15 H 90" class="dotted" style="--size:2px" />
    <path d="M10,25 H 90" class="dotted" style="--size:5px" />
  </g>
</svg>
```